# How to know what router is called by Magento programmaticaly?

Tags: magento

This is config.xml of some module:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Example>
            <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        </My_Example>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <first>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Example</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </first>
            <second>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>My_Example</module>
                    <frontName>test</frontName>
                </args>
            </second>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

I **deliberately** created same sections. I have read somewhere magento calls the last one.  But I would like to get this information in *test* controller via *var_dump* for example. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the route name of your module in the controller by:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use var_dump in magento.It will not work because of the php memory limit.Magento has some built in debugging functions.Google it for more info.

Comment: I mean any echo function to get this info. The aim is to get to know about test controller - which router does call it?